# How to set primary key on a field in fusion table

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I have a table named "Testing". fields in this table are Id,Name and Description.
I want to make Id field as a primary key i.e. only unique values should be entered in this field.

Thanks,
Himanshu

Comment: @corretge How to create index for fusion table in php.

Comment: ops Sorry, i don't see that you need a index in a Google Fustion table.

Answer (score 1):

When you do CREATE TABLE

In addition to the column names you specify in the CREATE TABLE statement, Google Fusion Tables will create a column named ROWID that contains an automatically-assigned, unique ID number for each row.

Comment: Thanks corretge. i also want a column which is auto incremented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this.  It appears to be a much requested feature: https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=112

Answer (score 0):

It's not available. I use a workaround that performs a COUNT(ROWID) query for the unqiue ID I'm about to insert and then take steps depending on whether or not that unique ID is already in the table.

The basic algo is something like this (using Google Apps Script):

```js
var check = FusionTables.Query.sql("SELECT COUNT(ROWID) FROM <table ID> WHERE 'Trip ID' = '" + rowID + "'");
    if (check.rows[0][0] > 0) {
      // ID already exists
     } else {
      // ID is new, insert the record.
     }
```